# Grails 2.5.6 issue

Tags: grails

I have a weird issue with my `Grails 2.5.6` application while running or debug when i change anything in the controller and press `save` and refresh the view page in the browser i found the below error occurs in the console and keeps occurring till i restart the application  , anyone got an idea from where is this error and how to fix it as i can't develop the controller

```
 java.sql.SQLException: The type registry TypeRegistry(id=2030320736,loader=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader) does not know about type id 3238
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:975)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractFindByPersistentMethod.getResult(AbstractFindByPersistentMethod.java:105)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractFindByPersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(AbstractFindByPersistentMethod.java:67)
```

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: @SyedSarek the IDE is IntelliJ ultimate

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA this problem occurs. It holds the development session with its own built-in configuration. Whenever you start your app by IntelliJ it will not effect itself for changing in controller till restart. It would be better to run your app via Command Prompt then your don't need to restart your app as you change in controller.

1. Open Command window in your Project Folder where `build.gradle` file situated
2. Then type `grails run-app` & press enter

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I did as what you mentioned and it was a nice workaround and worked fine, isn't there any solution for this issue on IntelliJ?

Comment: You may try this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html